# Changing wp_link_pages() to "Next Page" and "Previous Page" buttons?

Tags: posts, loop, pages, single, wp-link-pages

Currently I am using `<!--nextpage-->` to split a post into multiple pages, but I would like to change from `Pages: 1 2 3 4` to `Next Page` and `Previous Page` links similar to what you see on this [multipaged post](http://whatculture.com/film/kiss-kiss-bang-bang-10-awesome-images-youve-never-seen.php)

In my `single.php` I have:

```
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'pearl' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
```

How can I change this to a next and a previous button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `'next_or_number'` parameter:

```
wp_link_pages( array ( 'next_or_number' => 'next' ) );
```

See the [Codex for details](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages).